# Copying / directory to another directory [OS:Centos-7]

Tags: linux, centos, file-copy

I want to copy the `/` directory to another directory, i.e. `/Diskless-OS/centos-7/`. I have tried using `cp -r` command, but it is throwing an   "Permission Denied" error.

I'm working on a project where I'm developing a Diskless Booting System. So here, the Diskless Booting Clients, boot using the `/Diskless-OS/centos-7/` partition. Therefore I'm trying to copy the `/` partition.

Please provide me an appropriate command for performing the above. 
Images are attached below:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Copying the whole root directory is a highly unusual thing to want to do. The errors you get are due to `/proc` not being a regular filesystem, but a hierarchy of exposed kernel data structures. Likewise `/dev` (possibly other directories) contains special files that you may not actually want to copy, depending on what it is that you're _actually_ wanting to do. Also note that your target directory, `/Diskless-OS`, is located under `/` and is therefore one of the directories that will be copied.

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As already mentioned by Kusalananda, there are some directories you should not copy.
Therefore, you need to create them manually after copying the ones you need.
If you use Bash as shell, the following two commands should do what you want:

```
sudo cp -a /{b,e,h,l,m,o,ro,sb,sr,tf,u,v}* /Diskless-OS/
sudo mkdir /Diskless-OS/{dev,proc,run,sys,tmp}
```

The first command will copy all Directories except /dev, /Diskless-OS, /proc, /sys and /tmp.
The second command will then create the directories dev, proc, sys and tmp within the Diskless-OS directory.

Comment: It's one thing to copy all the files, it's another to turn the copy into a working system (which seems to be their intention). Also, you will break hard-links, which may mean that you will use more space than necessary.

Comment: Also, cp -a doesn’t save selinux context. This is probably moot for a diskless system because people always turn off selinux there.

Comment: @Kusalananda Are you saying `cp` on centos doesn't copy hard-links or is this just an assumption? `cp` on Debian 10 will copy hard-links! (just verified that).  Also, the OP is working on a "Diskless Booting System" projekt and asked for help to "... copy the / partition. ". I can't see that the OP asked for a Diskless Boot solution, which of course will need more work than just to copy the root directory.

Comment: I missed that `-a` option to `cp`, my apologies. And seeing that the user is obviously  happy with your answer, having accepted it, I won't e you on that other point either.